# Printing stars in triangle shape using for loops

Tags: c#, for-loop

I need to print something like this style in C#

```
*****
 ***
  *
```

how could I go about this?

So far I got the following code, but it prints the other way and reducing by one star.

```
int number = 5;
int i, j, k;
for (i = 1; i <= number; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= number - i; j++)
    {                    
        Console.Write("");
    }

    for (k = 1; k <= i; k++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: Although this will not solve your problem, but you should be using space instead of empty string like `Console.Write(" ");`

Comment: You're output wants only an odd number of stars.  Your code prints all of them.  And your output has them in the opposite direction as your code.  You need to get a handle on what your code is doing.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("*****\n *** \n  *");` no loops required

Comment: my god you are a genius!!

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code:

```
int number = 5;

for (int i = number; i >= 1; i -= 2)
{
    string spaces = new String(' ', (number - i) / 2);
    Console.WriteLine(spaces + new String('*', i) + spaces);
}
```

The main idea is to eliminate inner loops by using the [`String(char, count)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor.

Comment: although a churlish person might ponder as to whether that string constructor hides a loop

Comment: I took a look inside the constructor.  You get bonuses with this because a) you only need to allocate the memory for that string once and b) the loop uses pointers to break the computation into blocks of 4.  See CtorCharCount in System.String

Comment: Except the title of the question specifically states that the point of the exercise is to use `for` loops.  This is clearly someone learning to code, not someone looking for the most efficient way to print asterisks to the console!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take an input from your user, try this:

```
int number;
int i, j, k;
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
{
    for (i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        int numberOfSpaces = i;
        int numberOfStars = (number * 2 - 1) - (2 * numberOfSpaces);

        for (j = 1; j <= numberOfSpaces; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        for (k = 1; k <= numberOfStars; k++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("No number entered.");
}

Console.Read();
```

It is possible (and better) to do this with just one loop, but your approach also works, and as for loops are probably the point of the exercise your way is effective.  As I can see you are still learning, I tried to only change your code enough to make it work, but be aware that there are better ways to do this (such as the string building some of the other answers use).

It's helpful to think about what you're trying to do here.  You're want to **loop** through the lines and **calculate** the number of spaces and stars.

First you get the number of lines as an input string with ReadLine, then parse it into a number that can be used in your loop.  *note - if you haven't seen TryParse before, it is just a way to stop the user from crashing the program by entering a non-number.  It checks to see if the input can be parsed into a number and if it can, executes the program.*

Next, for each line you need to calculate how many characters you need.  Let's think about it for 3 lines.

- First line:  no spaces, 5 stars.
- Second line: 1 space each side, 3 stars.
- Third line: 2 spaces each side, 1 star.

From this we can see that you need twice as many characters as the number of lines, less 1.  (3*2 -1).  You can also see that you need a number of spaces equal to the number of the line you are on on each side (if the first line is numbered 0).  From this we can work out that we need a number stars equal to the number of characters, less 2 * the number of spaces.

Hope this helps you think about how to model the problem at hand!

Comment: This is a

*****
 ***
  *

Comment: I ran the code and it seemed to produce the result you are looking for, does it work for you?

Comment: What I really want to do is when a user enters a value it print that number of lines.


For example if the user enters 1 it will only print one *

if the user enters 3  it will print 
    *****
     ***
      *


if the user enters 4 it will print 

   *******
    *****
     ***
      *

Just like that.

Comment: OK, I will update my answer to include the option of entering a number of lines.  If it helps, please mark it as answer!

Answer (score 0):

CIRCLE shape 
guys try this.....

```
using System;

namespace Fan
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int circle_radius = 6; 
        double console_ratio = Convert.ToDouble(4.0 / 2.0);
        double a = console_ratio * circle_radius;
        double b = circle_radius;

        for (int y = -circle_radius; y <= circle_radius; y++)
        {
            for (double x = -console_ratio * circle_radius; x <= console_ratio * circle_radius; x++)
            {
                double d = (x / a) * (x / a) + (y / b) * (y / b);
                if (d > 0.90 && d < 1.2)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
                   Console.Read();
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CODE:**

```
 int index = 20;
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 20 - index; k++)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < index; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }
                for (int k = 0; k < index; k++)
                {
                    Console.Write("*");
                }

                index--;
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```csharp
using System;

public class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    int number = 5;

    for (int i = number, b = 0; i >= 1; i -= 2, b++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', b) + new string('*', i));
    } 
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
For number = 5
*****
 ***
  *

For number = 10
**********
 ********
  ******
   ****
    **
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public enum shape{
        square,
        triangle
    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
                {
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(j,i);
                    if (IsInShape(shape.square ,i,j))
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static bool IsInShape(shape s, int i, int j)
        {
            if (s == shape.square)
            {
                return ((Math.Pow((i - 7), 2) + Math.Pow((j - 7), 2)) <= 12);
            }
            else
            {
                return (j - i > 0 && j+i < 6);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: A better answer would be if you found a way to do it with 1 loop

Comment: mine can also do squares

Comment: Hah, great enthusiasm!  Unfortunately, I think the best answer eliminated the extra loops.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29629394/printing-stars-in-triangle-shape-using-for-loops/29629524#29629524